# Setup Bootstrap for Visual Basic Setup Toolkit - EXE - silent installation (VB6)

Tags: windows, powershell, vb6, exe, windows-task-scheduler

We have an old application which uses has it's executable (EXE) build on VB6 (Setup Bootstrap for Visual Basic Setup Toolkit ). We are trying to silently install the setup by  and running it in a scheduled manner using task scheduler.

Command use : Start-Process -FilePath "D:\SETUPXXX.EXE" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "/qn"

While running this stand alone from a power shell console or command line the setup executes and shows up on the screen , completes installation and goes off(without clicking anything). This installs is successfully.

But wherever we are trying to schedule this on a task scheduler it doesn't pop up anything and neither it installs the application.

We tried other ways "setupxxx.exe /sc:\setup.log" but the results are same it works when executed from command line and pops up the installation completes but fails to do the same when scheduled or run as a batch file.

Is there a way to stop the installer popup coming which might be stopping the instillation while running.

Refer :https://theether.net/kb/100165

Comment: `-Verb RunAs` _interactively_ prompts for privilege elevation (running as admin), which I wouldn't expect to work in a non-interactive context such as a scheduled task. Instead, remove the `-Verb RunAs`  part and configure your scheduled task to `Run with highest privileges`. Also, if you want your task to wait for the installation to finish, add `-Wait`.

Comment: This works but when you run with an option "Run only when user is logged on option" but fails to run when mentioned "Run whether user is logged on or not". Run with Highest privileges is also set. We need to make it run in a scheduled manner.

Comment: Possibly posting this question on Superuser.com might get more answers, unless you have solved it already. If you have, you can add an answer yourself to benefit others in the future.